# Ubuntu 13.04: LDAP invalid credentials

Tags: 13.04, ldap, openldap

I'm trying to follow the Ubuntu official OpenLDAPServer guide with no success.

When I tried to log into the server it says( https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openldap-server.html#openldap-server-populate):

```
root@dexter:~# ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f add_content.ldif
Enter LDAP Password: 
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Also when I try to get the dc=example,dc=com DIT:

```
root@dexter:~# ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=example,dc=com dn
No such object (32)
```

Any ideas? I've reinstalled the service three times and I'm completly sur that the password is fine.

Comment: Is the base DN really dc=example,dc=com? Or did you change it during package install? What's the output of `sudo ls -l /etc/ldap/slapd.d/`?

Comment: @ericcarvalho you're right, but according to the doc this should be created...root@dexter:~# sudo ls -l /etc/ldap/slapd.d/ total 8 drwxr-x--- 3 openldap openldap 4096 may 14 09:32 cn=config -rw------- 1 openldap openldap 478 may 14 09:32 cn=config.ldif

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the file /etc/hosts, I had several entries for my localhost and the installation didn't create the Base DN.

TO fix that clean your /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1       dexter.example.com  dexter
```

Change "dexter" with your hostname.

Comment: what's the distinction between 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1?  They're both loopbacks.